# Any need for a [modern c++] tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

There are tags specific for each version of modern C++.

Sometimes when asking a question more related to design, I believe it would make sense to tag with [modern C++], assuming C++11 or above and modern design pattern (i.e design pattern taking benefit of those versions).

Comment: Definition might be too nebulous. What would happen in a few years once the *current* versions used are not considered modern anymore? I think this'd be superfluous with the already existing version tags.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Definition *may* not be [so nebulous](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/what-is-modern-c#:~:text=Modern%20C%2B%2B%20stands%20for%20C%2B%2B,14%2C%20and%20C%2B%2B17.&text=The%20first%20is%20called%20classical,after%202011%20is%20totally%20different.) From my own POV, I can say that I became 'familiar' with Modern C++ only after I became active on SO. Before that, I lived in an isolated universe where using `new int[n]` was still OK and `std::vector<int>` looked strange.

Comment: I disagree - definition is _not_ too nebulous.  Post-C++11 standards make some things easier or possible but it is possible to distinguish both "modern" from "pre-modern" and also "modern" from "latest-and-greatest" (the latter being what the `c++` tag is according to the tag wiki).

Answer (score 11):

I don't think we need it. The guidelines in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) wiki specify this when the tag is on its own

> Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C++
> standard is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That
> is, whichever version of ISO 14882 that ISO currently lists as active.
> Please have this in mind when answering or commenting on questions
> tagged c++.

So just tagging "C++" is enough to convey "modern approaches welcome". And there's nothing stopping newer answers to old questions with just this tag. As the language evolves, more modern solutions to old problems are still encouraged.

**TL;DR** - The "modern" is already implied by tagging "C++".

Comment: Maybe an [old-style-C++] would be a more useful tag?

Comment: @AdrianMole - I counter with [tag:c++03]. If you need a limit, we have those explicitly.

Comment: But (IIRC) that already had strange, new-fangled things like `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: However, I can't help but agreeing that a *tag* would not be especially useful.

Comment: @AdrianMole - I fail to see you point about `std::vector`. Either way, there is no symmetry between `[old-style-C++]` and `[modern-C++]`. Nobody asks "how can I solve it in the most archaic fashion ever". Instead, they may need to support only upto a certain standard, and for that we have revision tags.

Comment: Maybe there are some embedded systems/compilers that don't implement the STL, And, of course, there is always [tag:turbo-c++] ...

Comment: @AdrianMole - For which we have a tag. And standalone implementations does not automatically mean archaic. It's a false dichotomy.

Comment: Whoa - I'm ***agreeing*** with you, after all!

Comment: @AdrianMole - I sometimes have that effect.

Comment: But "modern" is _not_ implied by tagging `c++`.  According to the wording quoted tagging `c++` from the tag wiki means the version current at the time of asking the question.  (Right now that would be `c++20`.) "Modern" generally means lambdas, move semantics, variadic templates, type traits, and such, introduced in C++ and extended/improved since then, plus the entire panoply of programming techniques built on them. Yes, post-C++11 standards make some things easier or possible but it is possible to distinguish both "modern" from "pre-modern" and also "modern" from "latest-and-greatest".

Answer (score -4):

The brief description of the `c++` tag says

> C++ is a general-purpose programming language. It was originally designed as an extension to C and has a similar syntax, but it is now a completely different language. Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler. Use a version-specific tag for questions related to a specific standard revision [C++11], [C++14], [C++17], [C++20] or [C++23], etc.

Yes, as [answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402757/751579), the *full* `c++` tag wiki says the tag, without other qualifications, applies to the latest-and-greatest standard (at the time of the question).  But the above is what you see when you hover over the `c++` tag or click on it to get the tag's questions - which I imagine is where most users stop looking.  And it says its for "code to be compiled with a C++ compiler".  Full stop.

"Modern" generally means lambdas, move semantics, variadic templates, type traits, and such, introduced in C++ and extended/improved since then, plus the entire panoply of programming techniques built on them. Yes, post-C++11 standards make some things easier or possible but it is possible to distinguish both "modern" from "pre-modern" and also "modern" from "latest-and-greatest".

There should be a `modern-c++` tag.  The reason I'm here answering this meta-question now is because I had a need for it.

Comment: Your definition of "modern" is not going to last very long. Especially with the release of C++20 and the many features that come with it. And even C++20 is not going to be modern for long. Anyway, you said you have a need for this tag; do you mind sharing that post? I would like to see an example of where such a tag might be applicable.